# Producing xml output with nosetests --processes

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose

I am struggling to get `nosetests` to output `xml`.

I have installed `nosexml`, then in by `PYTHONPATH` typed `ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ elementtree`.

Now I can type `nosetests -plugins` and get a list of plugins including `xunit`.

If I run

```
nosetests  --with-xunit test.py
```

then I get a file 'nosetests.xml' with test results. So I try to run nose as follows,

```
nosetests  --with-xunit --processes=1 --process-timeout=8000 test.py
```

and get a file 'nosetests.xml' that says no tests run.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><testsuite name="nosetests" tests="0" errors="0" failures="0" skip="0"></testsuite>
```

Can I use `--with-xunit` with other options?

Answer (score 2):

Recently solution appeared - [xunitmp](https://github.com/Ignas/nose_xunitmp). Checked - works for me.

Answer (score 1):

It is a [bug](https://github.com/nose-devs/nose/issues/2) in the xunit plug-in.
By what I see it was not fixed, so at the moment there is no way to use `--processes` and `--with-xunit` options together.